# How to reload previously loaded classes that changed during runtime?

Tags: java, classloader

I'm writing an application that needs to reload a previously loaded class during runtime. The reason is that the class is auto-generated during runtime, and the new implementation changes the way the app works. I generate only one object of the said class, and I stripped it from all dependencies but an interface that defines constant values. There's no problem reseting the values of any or all of the members when reloading. I know exactly when it changes and I can control it. The only problem I have is the reload itself.

From what I read, I should use a ClassLoader. I tried to do so, but I can't make it work.

I tried the following:

- Getting the current ClassLoader (`myClassObject.getClass().getClassLoader()`) and using it to reload the class - Doesn't work. It probably keeps loading the old implementation.
- Generating my own (AKA copy-paste from SO with modifications) - Doesn't work because the ClassLoader I generate is different than the one that generated the class (Exception: myClass cannot be casted to myClass).
- Creating a constructor that sets the ClassLoader of the superclass doesn't seem to have any effect.
- Using my new ClassLoader to generate the class that has myClassObject as a member solved the ClassLoader mismatch for myClassObject, but created a new mismatch one level up. I used `getClassLoader()` everytime and I see they don't match.
- I tried adding `-Djava.system.class.loader=com.test.Reoader com.test.myMainClass` to make it my default reloader, but I get an error from the compiler.
- Google keeps pointing me back to the same stuff I read already.
- **EDIT:** I tried creating an interface and reload the class implementing it. That didn't solve it either.

I know I should override the default ClassLoader, but nothing I do seems to succeed at that.

My ClassLoader:

```
public class Reloader extends ClassLoader {

    public Reloader(){
        super(Reloader.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> loadClass(String s) {
        return findClass(s);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> findClass(String s) {
        try {
            byte[] bytes = loadClassData(s);
            return defineClass(s, bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            try {
                return super.loadClass(s);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ignore) {}
            ioe.printStackTrace(java.lang.System.out);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private byte[] loadClassData(String className) throws IOException {
        File f = new File("out\\production\\ManoCPU\\" + className.replaceAll("\\.", "/") + ".class");
        int size = (int) f.length();
        byte buff[] = new byte[size];
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
        dis.readFully(buff);
        dis.close();
        return buff;
    }
}
```

Thanks very much to anyone that can help.

Comment: How does the class get autogenerated?

Comment: I have a compiler that reads a template file and compiles it into java code. The template file can be changed and compiled within the application.

Comment: Does it happen very often? I mean how many times could the class be recompiled?

Comment: It really depends. Someone can decide to use the current template and there will be no changes at all during the whole session, but if someone decides to change the template, he'll probably compile it several times with minor fixes until it works exactly as intended.

Answer (score 1):

You can only load a class once (per instance of a classloader). That means you have to throw away the classloader you have loaded your class with and instantiate a new one for your updated version of the class.

When dealing with multiple class loaders also have in mind that if you load the same class with several classloaders they are NOT recognized as being the same class.

Comment: Thanks. I've read that same thing everywhere I looked, but how do I throw away the old one? That's what I can't figure out. I don't need it to be the same class it just implements some methods whose functionality changes, and the only two members are updated whenever a method is called.

Comment: I would suggest looking into the source code of some open source plugin framework where multiple classloaders are involved. the tomcat source code may also be possible.